# is the accusative used after an infinitive?

Tags: translation

the song "If I Had Words", the phrase "to make a day for you" is used and I'd like to translate it. Fari tagon or fari tago?

Answer (score 4):

The tense or form of the verb doesn't matter. If the verb is transitive, the direct object should be in the accusative.

Having said that the Esperanto expression *fari tagon* literally means, that you fabricate or produce an object such as a day, as if you were a god making the day to rise. The English expression "to make a day" is an idiom with a different meaning: to make someone happy or be a source of satisfaction, for the rest of the day. To make someone happy is in Esperanto [*feliĉigi*](http://vortaro.net/#feli%C4%89igi):

- *Bonaj infanoj gepatrojn feliĉigas* (by Zamenhof)

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer.  The  song does indicate a wish to actually create a day, with specific attributes, rather than just make someone happy.

Comment: Poems and thereby songs are hard to translate. They are full of figurative expressions and the words should have a certain rhythm. If you can provide more context, lyrics, perhaps someone can give you a more singable translation.